# How to get m.request get data 'length' in mithril js model and controller?

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

I am newbie mithril js developer, i create sample code mithril js using web services get data return value in controller. i confused please help. I have create below code

**Model**

```
var User = {
        userlist:function(){
            return m.request({
                method:'GET',
                url:'//localhost:6500/getAllusers',
                config:function(xhr, options){
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('x-access-token', Auth.token())
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

**controller**

```
var home ={
    controller:function(){
        this.pages = Users.userlist()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do things like this: (use m.request(args).then() )

```
var User = {
    got_user_data:function(data){
         //data is what you get from url:'//localhost:6500/getAllusers'
    },
    userlist:function(){
       return m.request({
            method:'GET',
            url:'//localhost:6500/getAllusers',
            config:function(xhr, options){
                xhr.setRequestHeader('x-access-token', Auth.token())
            }
        }).then(User.got_user_data);
    }
}
```